# Find usages of classes/functions in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Let's say I have this file1.js:

```
function MyClass() { }

MyClass.prototype = {
    getName: function(){
        return this.name;
    },

    setName: function(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
};
module.exports = MyClass;
```

And in file2.js:

```
var MyClass = require('./file1');

var x = new MyClass();

x.setName('Bob');
console.log(x.getName());
```

Thing is, from file1.js, I want to be able to find all usages of MyClass.

I tried using the Ctrl+G command (Find Usages) on MyClass, but it is not showing the usage from file2. Which is funny, because somehow WebStorm knows x is a MyClass instance. For example, While at file2, I'm able to CTRL+click on the `x = new MyClass()` line and it goes directly to its definition on file1.js. I am even able, from file1, to find usage of the methods getName/setName, and it shows it correctly, it's not even a 'word' search, because I tried creating another MyClass in a third file with the same methods, just to check if I could trick the IDE, but Webstorm is smart, he definitively knows that x is a instance of MyClass.

So, is there a way to achieve what I want: find usages of classes/functions like that? I know that I can find usages from the file itself, but it isn't what I want, because I could be exporting more things...